# Issues resolving xml for preferences screen

Tags: android, xml, preferences, preferenceactivity

Ok, I feel slightly stupid.  I am getting the following error:

xml cannot be resolved or is not a field

right at this line:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); <--- this line has error
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Very frustrating for a new person like myself :(

EDIT: i have a file named preferences.xml located in a folder named xml under res.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to include the string in the strings.xml file which i called from the manifest.

    <activity android:name=".Preferences"
        android:label="@string/set_preferences"> </activity>

needed to add

    <string name="set_preferences">set_preferences</string>

to strings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I forgot to include the string in the strings.xml file which i called from the manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".Preferences"
    android:label="@string/set_preferences"> </activity>
```

needed to add

```
<string name="set_preferences">set_preferences</string> to strings.xml
```